# Creating a button with a background and foreground image

Tags: css

I have a small issue trying to get the following to work, and am not sure if it is something that CSS3 is designed to deal with or not. I have looked around and found that multiple background images are supported, however trying the many examples have resulted in nada.

This is the primary CSS code for rendering my buttons:

```
.button {
    background:#eee url(images/button.gif) repeat-x 0 0;
    border:solid 1px #b1a874;
    color:#7f7f7f;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:2px 6px 2px 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:14px !important;
}
```

The above code produces the standard buttons which are fine. But now I want to add icons on certain buttons, such as a print button. I use 2 sets of additional CSS class:

```
input.addImage {
    background-repeat: no-repeat;  /* once */
    background-position: 5px 2px;  
    padding-left: 16px;     
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And:

```
input.Print {
    background-image: url(../img/buttons/print.png); /* 16px x 16px */
}
```

As you can see my image is in fact 16x16 which fits nicely into the buttons. However the original background image is stripped away completly, leaving the background color as transparent.

I am sure that if its possible, its something basic I am overlooking, and look forward to figuring this out.

Finally the code for the button:

```
<input type="button" class="button addImage Print" ... >
```

Thank you for your valuable time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you apply a property in CSS, it completely overwrites any previously defined property for that element.  What you need to do is tell it to apply 2 backgrounds to the element, which is done like this:

```
.button.Print {
    background-image: url(images/button.gif), url(../img/buttons/print.png);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly this code also makes the button.gif background for the button repeat only once as well. I have indeed tried this :(

Comment: Then you need to use the longhand form in the same way:  `background: #eee url(images/button.gif) repeat-x, url(../img/buttons/print.png) no-repeat 5px 2px`

Comment: When you said longhand I tried and it didnt work, so I merged it into a single class and it worked. It wasnt the way I wanted to go, but you were right.

Answer (score 1):

Multiple backgrounds is only supported within the same CSS class / element definition. Means, you have to set both backgrounds in `.button`.

Your `.print` has to contain the default background too seperated by a comma and followed with your `print.png` icon.

**edit**

My answer wasn't really clear about that. you have to specify the background first, which should be on top of the other one. Here's some example code with random pictures.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/RzWfp/

```
.button {
    background-image: url(http://www.myinkblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2009/02/background2.jpg);
    border:solid 1px #b1a874;
    color:#7f7f7f;
    font-size:11px;
    padding:2px 6px 2px 6px;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:14px !important;
}

.button-test {
    background-image:  url(http://www.famfamfam.com/lab/icons/silk/icons/feed.png), url(http://www.tutorial9.net/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/air-balloon-gradient.jpg);   
    background-position: left center, center center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    padding-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunatly, like the first response, this results in the button.gif only being displayed once, barely visible.

Comment: Err, it IS working! you just have to specify the "overlaying" image first. At first the print.png and *then* the button.gif. Example code: http://jsfiddle.net/RzWfp/

Comment: Thank you again for your time, I ended up using the advise of you both in somehwat 'optimizing' (if you will) the final result. If I could upvote, I would for you both, but im not at 15 rep yet haha.